# Finding the source event that triggered ajaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this sample that i am fiddling with - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7By8/)

From inside the ajaxError event (see code),

HOW do you find source event that raised the ajaxError? (in this case the click event on the #global dom should be the source)

```
$('html').ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
    if (!handledLocally){
        if (xhr.status == 404) {
            alert("html error callback");    
        }
        handledLocally = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the ajax request handlers, an id will need to be assigned (manually or automatically) to the element that triggered the event. You could then send this id as an additional key-value pair in the request (element_id:THEID) and grab it with various substring methods in the ajax request handlers.

Comment: do you have a more generic way of doing this? I don't have the time to go through all my code and attach ids.

Answer (score 0):

Another generic way that requires least setup is to use activeElement property of the event target.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (e) {
    try {
        var $el = $(e.target.activeElement);
        console.log($el);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
});
```